# Fade in / Fade out with hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I would like to implement a Fade in / Fade out effect on my hover, How Can I do this cause I need to keep position of cursor for Text Displayed.

http://jsfiddle.net/u3pW8/34/

```
    $(function() {
    $("#static .wrapper").hover(function (e) {
        var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        $(this).children(".hidden-content").css("left", relX);
    });
});
```

Thx for help !

Comment: Can you re-formulate your question? I'm not sure I got it. The hidden text should follow the cursor when displayed? Or stay where it is?

Comment: hidden text should follow the cursor.

Comment: So it's working as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS3 transition:

```
.hidden-content {
    position: absolute;
    opacity:0;
    display:block;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}

.wrapper:hover .hidden-content {
    opacity:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u3pW8/35/

Comment: hmm no problem with old browsers like IE ?

Comment: Here a table of compatible browsers :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility So only IE10+ works.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your code. This should work.
I added this line among other things:

`$(this).children(".hidden-content").fadeIn('slow');`

http://jsfiddle.net/u3pW8/37/

Comment: this works for the OP, because it's compatible in all browsers.